# Error in Perl modules which are already installed

Tags: perl, perl-module

I was using local library and I install the modules in my local library but now when i test my code now its giving following . I tried to install Net Particia again but its giving second error

1st error

```
Can't locate Net/Patricia.pm
```

2nd error

> cpan> install Math::Round
>
> Undefined subroutine &Compress::Zlib::gzopen called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN.pm line 5721.

Please guide . I think the issue is with CPAN . One thing I want to share is this because to limited space to my login as my ID is full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Perl installation is broken - at one time it included Compress::Zlib, but now it's gone. If this rings a bell and you know how to repair it, do so and attempt the Net::Patricia installation again in the CPAN client.

If not, install Compress::Zlib manually and then afterwards try again with the CPAN client:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PM/PMQS/IO-Compress-2.061.tar.gz
tar -xf IO-Compress-2.061.tar.gz
cd IO-Compress-2.061/
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install    # into your local library
```